# The opposite of functools.partial

Tags: python

There is a library function that takes a callback and calls it with some arguments:

```python
def library_function(callback):
    # crunching numbers
    callback(result)
```

I don't need the result but I still want to handle the fact that the library function has finished, so I pass a nullary function as a callback. It results in "invalid argument count" error, so I have to wrap my callback with a lambda to ignore the argument:

```python
def nullary_callback():
    print("Handled!")

library_function(lambda x: nullary_callback())
```

`functools.partial` does the opposite task: binding a certain argument and reducing the arity of the function. Is there any standard helper that increases the arity ignoring newly added arguments, so I can replace my lambda with it, or my approach is already pythonic enough?

Comment: No, there is not function which arbitrarily increases the airty of a function. `library_function(lambda x: nullary_callback())` seems reasonable enough.

Comment: could just `def nullary_callback(arg):` because its identical to the lambda. If you cant change the nullary callback for whatever reason, the lambda is perfectly acceptable. I use a lot of lambdas in event listeners, especially for button clicks when the name of the function is less important than its functionality (since its identity is better represented by the button).

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't your `nullary_callback` simply have a parameter you don't use? That would make it a valid callback for where you're using it.

If you need a generic callback that always works (because it never does anything):

```
def nullary_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Handled!")


library_function(nullary_callback)
```

Comment: The nullary callback is used in multiple other places, and it intentionally has no arguments to avoid possible errors due to it being called with arguments somewhere else. Moreover, in some places I have to use nullary callback whose code I don't control.

Comment: Then I assume the provided solution is what you require? Please accept the answer with the checkmark so your question no longer shows as unanswered - or let me know if it doesn't meet your need.

Comment: I explained two reasons why it doesn't meet my needs: at one place I want `nullary_callback` have no arguments to avoid possible errors; at the other place I cannot modify neither `library_function` nor `nullary_callback` so I have to wrap it with something.

Comment: Did you actually read and try my solution? With `*args` and `*kwargs` no arguments are required and any arguments are allowed - how does that not meet your need? You were asking for the most pythonic solution - this is most definitely it

Comment: I do know what `*args` and `**kwargs` mean. I want to avoid the possibility of someone calling `nullary_callback(123)` because this would lead to an error (arguments are ignored while the caller may expect them to be used). Regarding the second reason – obviously I cannot add `*args` and `**kwargs` to the function whose code I cannot modify.

Comment: So, you want to modify a callback for which you have no access to the source to pass it to a function for which you also have no access to the source? Can you provide an example where that actually makes sense? The solution provided here is how you extend your own function with room for arguments that can be ignored - I fail to come up with a scenario where what you appear to be asking for is actually useful (or a good idea at all)

Comment: I want to deal with excessive arguments **only at the certain point of call**, not everywhere where the function is called. And you don't even address my second argument (where I cannot modify the callback).

Comment: *Can you provide an example where that actually makes sense?* Sure. The `library_function` is a button. It accepts the callback `on_pressed` and calls it with `self` so I may understand which button is pressed. I want to have the button to, say, reload the application. So I provide `reload_app` callback to the button. I don't care which button is pressed since I provide this callback only to one button. And it would be weird to have `reload_app` accepting any arguments since it is nullary in essence.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that example makes no sense to me if you have no control over the source of the callback (as you previously claimed) and "it would be weird to have reload_app accepting any arguments since it is nullary in essence" is just wrong. No, it makes perfect sense and is pythonic to have it accept `*args` and `**kwargs` (you can name them differently, the key thing is the unpacking operators and these are standard names) if you cannot predict how the function will be called, or if you don't care. It appears you are here to have an argument, not to learn anything or solve a problem.